# Перезапустить докер контейнер с консольным PHP

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

Иногда мне нужно заставить процесс перечитать свой конфиг, или свой исходный код, если это скрипт.

Как я это делаю:

- Nginx: `docker-compose exec nginx sh -c 'nginx -s reload'` - у Nginx есть для этого специальный сигнал
- unbound: `docker-compose exec dns sh -c 'unbound-control reload'`
- php-fpm: `docker-compose exec php-fpm sh -c 'kill 1'` - просто прибиваю процесс PID 1, а в `docker-compose.yml` стоит политика перезапуска `restart: always`, поэтому контейнер перезапускается

И так далее. Если перечитывание не предусмотрено, то помогает `kill 1`.

И вот столкнулся с непонятным поведением: `kill 1` не работает. Итак, по порядку.

Есть докер-контейнер, в котором выполняется консольная команда `php /var/www/artisan queue:work --sleep=1`, она держит соединение с Redis и обрабатывает очереди.

Я выполняю в этом контейнере `kill 1`, и ничего не происходит. Сама программа продолжает успешно обрабатывать очереди.

`ps aux`:

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.1  0.1 183592 50544 ?        Ss   19:11   0:10 php /var/www/artisan queue:work --sleep=1
```

Почему такая ситуация? Из-за ожидания ввода-вывода? Или игнорирование сигналов?

PS. Конечно, я могу перезапустить контейнер средствами докера. Но интересно, почему такая ситуация.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kill` по умолчанию посылает `SIGTERM`, который может быть перехвачен самим процессом и проигнорирован. Вероятно, это и происходит. Можно через какое-то время посылать `SIGKILL`, который не может быть перехвачен (`kill -9 1`)

---

Ещё и баги у них были, так что стоит проверить свою версию

https://divinglaravel.com/queue-workers-how-they-work

---

> Конечно, я могу перезапустить контейнер средствами докера. Но интересно, почему такая ситуация.

Это, кстати, будет самое правильное, потому что `docker stop` как раз сначала пошлёт `SIGTERM`, а потом `SIGKILL`.

Из документации https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/

> The main process inside the container will receive SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL.

Comment: `kill -9 1` я также пробовал, и ноль реакции. `docker restart` помогает, но вот если он шлет сначала SIGTERM а потом SIGKILL, и это работает, то почему отправка вручную - нет? PS `docker stop` также сработал без проблем.

Comment: Посмотрел `Worker.php`. И там стоит условие перехвата сигналов `extension_loaded('pcntl');`. Это расширение не загружено, поэтому скрипт игнорит. Сейчас попробую поставить.

Comment: Да, скрипт игнорировал сигналы по причине отсутствия модуля pcntl. Установка его решила проблему, kill 1 заработал.

Comment: `kill 1` заработал. Я добавил в либу `echo "SIGTERM" . PHP_EOL;` чтобы увидеть в логе докера как пришел этот сигнал. И я увидел. А странное здесь то, что `docker container stop ...` не вызывает показ этого сообщения, а в логе `queue-worker_1 exited with code 137`

Comment: `137` 
означает `SIGKILL` 
https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-docker-container-exit-codes-5ee79a1d58f6

Comment: Что намекает на то, что `pcntl` не загрузился - может ты по ошибке старый image запустил? Между `docker stop` и `docker container stop` не должно быть разницы

Comment: Нет, ошибка "запустил не тот контейнер" исключена. Контейнеры поднимает docker-compose, и через его же лог видно что происходит. Образ я тоже пересобрал. Видно как вызывается функция которая навешивает обработчик сигналов, а вот вызов происходит если кидать `kill 1`, а docker stop - нет. Фантастика

Comment: Внутри `docker-cli` ровно одна команда `stop`, так что она не может работать по разному. Она даже не знает, как её вызвали
Команда https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/cli/command/container/stop.go
Там функция `NewStopCommand`, которая создаёт обработчик.  
Вот её добавляют в контейнер https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/c0a6b1c7b30203fbc28cd619acb901a95a80e30e/cli/command/container/cmd.go#L35
Вот её добавляют в корень https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/c0a6b1c7b30203fbc28cd619acb901a95a80e30e/cli/command/commands/commands.go#L111